# Advantages of using Cox model versus logistic GEE?

Tags: survival, panel-data, cox-model, generalized-estimating-equations, kaplan-meier

What are the advantages of  using Cox proportional hazards model versus logistic GEE? Can one generate Kaplan-Meier remainder estimator curves using logistic GEE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two advantages to Cox models for survival data:

1. They deal with censoring, logistic regression doesn't.
2. They allow survival time, rather than just survive/did not. This usually provides more power and is often a more relevant question.

You don't say what your variables are, but let's suppose they are "surgery vs. not" and "death".  It's usually important to distinguish "died in one day" from "died in 10 years".

Comment: What about poisson gee which can tell me how many deaths at a particular time?

Comment: Poisson GEE does not deal with censoring.

Comment: You mean if someone dies and then we don’t have anymore data with them and GEE can’t deal with I forgot MCAR or MAR? What about with the geeglm package where I can specify waves and if someone dies, I can just not record them in the data and the gee still runs perfectly?

Comment: No, I mean if someone DOESN'T die then you don't know how long they would have lived.

Comment: I may calculate the probability of a particular person dying on a specific day. May I makeup a threshold for probability and say if probability that they die is less than someone number, then they live? Using that I can guess days until probability meets that threshold to predict how long they live?

Comment: Assume I’m using logistic gee where time and treatment are predictors.

Comment: If you want to "make up" and "guess" things, then you can do this. If you want to use statistical analysis, you should use the Cox model.

Comment: Is a disadvantage of coxph that I have to specify the full likelihood? With GEE I use fisher scoring. Full likelihood isn’t always calculable.

Comment: If I ran poisson gee to predict number of living individuals at some time assuming a fixed cohort and then I can calculate when the first person will die. That tells me how many days they would have lived

Comment: Is that estimate inaccurate? I mean only if the poisson model is flawed right? How do?

Comment: You do NOT have to specify the full likelihood with Cox.